# Regarding the output of a query

Tags: sql, oracle

I have one query that I have below two tables ..

```
CREATE table "EMPLOYEE" (
    "EMP_ID"     NUMBER,
    "ENAME"      VARCHAR2(4000),
    "SALARY"     VARCHAR2(4000),
    "COMPANY"    VARCHAR2(4000),
    "CONTACTNO." NUMBER,
    "GENDER"     CHAR(100),
    constraint  "EMPLOYEE_PK" primary key ("EMP_ID")
)

CREATE TABLE  "DEPARTMENT" 
(   
    "DEPT_ID" NUMBER, 
    "DEPT_NAME" VARCHAR2(4000), 
    "LOCATION" VARCHAR2(4000), 
    "CONTACTNO." NUMBER, 
     CONSTRAINT "DEPARTMENT_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("DEPT_ID") ENABLE
)
```

Now what will be the output If I write select * from EMPLOYEE,DEPARTMENT

Comment: You would get a cartesian product of your two tables. Meaning, if there's 5,000 rows in your employee table and 20 rows in department table, you would get 100,000 rows in your query.

Comment: @MichaelBuen If I had 4 rows in both the table then what would be the total number of rows in both the table, it is 4*4=16 or it is every row of the first table is matched against every row of the second table that is 64 (16+16+16+16)..! Please advise

Comment: This is a trivially easy question to answer through experimentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With only a schema, nothing. If the tables had data, you'd get a cross-join of everything in each table.

Comment: yeah the tables have data , but there is no linkage between the two tales both the tables are independent , Please advise still I get the cross join..!

Comment: The query you asked about returns a cross-join of the two tables because no condition for the join has been specified. That means every row of the first table is matched against every row of the second table. That's the basic notion of what a "cross join" is.

Answer (score 1):

The comma operator returns a cross join of the two tables. This is the Cartesian product of the tables involved in the join.

Comment: yeah the tables have data , but there is no linkage between the two tales both the tables are independent , Please advise still I get the cross join..!

Comment: It will still be a cross join if the tables are related or not. Just a heads up if you weren't aware, using the comma join syntax in Oracle is really oldschool. People tend to use more ANSI sql nowadays